# JavaScript : How to split an audio blob into 1 second chunks and export to wav files using recorder.js?

Tags: javascript, audio, chunks, recorder, web-mediarecorder

I want to record voice, split the recorded voice (or the audio blob) automatically into 1 second chunks, export each chunk to a wav file and send to the back end . This should happen asynchronously while the user speaks.

I currently use the following recorder.js library to do the above tasks 
https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js

My problem is, with time the blob/wave file becomes bigger in size. I think it is because the data gets accumulated and make the chunk size bigger. So with time I am not actually sending sequential 1 second chunks but accumulated chunks.

I can’t figure our where in my code this issue is caused. May be this happens inside the recorder.js library. If someone has used recorder js or any other JavaScript method for a similar tasks, appreciate if you could go through this code and let me know where it breaks.

This is my JS code

```js
var gumStream; // Stream from getUserMedia()
var rec; // Recorder.js object
var input; // MediaStreamAudioSourceNode we'll be recording
var recordingNotStopped; // User pressed record button and keep talking, still not stop button pressed
const trackLengthInMS = 1000; // Length of audio chunk in miliseconds
const maxNumOfSecs = 1000; // Number of mili seconds we support per recording (1 second)


// Shim for AudioContext when it's not available. 
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext //audio context to help us record

var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");

//Event handlers for above 2 buttons
recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);

//Asynchronous function to stop the recoding in each second and export blob to a wav file
const sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));

const asyncFn = async() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < maxNumOfSecs; i++) {
    if (recordingNotStopped) {
      rec.record();
      await sleep(trackLengthInMS);
      rec.stop();

      //stop microphone access
      gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

      //Create the wav blob and pass it on to createWaveBlob
      rec.exportWAV(createWaveBlob);
    }
  }
}

function startRecording() {
  console.log("recordButton clicked");
  recordingNotStopped = true;
  var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: false
  }

  recordButton.disabled = true;
  stopButton.disabled = false;

  //Using the standard promise based getUserMedia() 
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {

    //Create an audio context after getUserMedia is called
    audioContext = new AudioContext();

    // Assign to gumStream for later use 
    gumStream = stream;

    //Use the stream 
    input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    //Create the Recorder object and configure to record mono sound (1 channel)
    rec = new Recorder(input, {
      numChannels: 1
    });

    //Call the asynchronous function to split and export audio
    asyncFn();
    console.log("Recording started");

  }).catch(function(err) {
    //Enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    stopButton.disabled = true;
  });
}

function stopRecording() {
  console.log("stopButton clicked");
  recordingNotStopped = false;

  //disable the stop button and enable the record button to  allow for new recordings
  stopButton.disabled = true;
  recordButton.disabled = false;

  //Set the recorder to stop the recording
  rec.stop();

  //stop microphone access
  gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
}

function createWaveBlob(blob) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  //Convert the blob to a wav file and call the sendBlob function to send the wav file to the server
  var convertedfile = new File([blob], 'filename.wav');
  sendBlob(convertedfile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorder.js keeps a record buffer of the audio that it records.  When `exportWAV` is called, the record buffer is encoded but not cleared.  You'd need to call `clear` on the recorder before calling `record` again so that the previous chunk of audio is cleared from the record buffer.

This is how it was fixed in the above code.

```
//Extend the Recorder Class and add clear() method
Recorder.prototype.step = function () {
    this.clear();
};

//After calling the exportWAV(), call the clear() method
rec.exportWAV(createWaveBlob);
rec.step();
```